# Catch and display on the page any error in a .NET Maui Blazor project

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, maui, maui-blazor

For testing purpose, I would like to 'catch' any error occuring in my app and displaying it on the page (not in the console). For that purpose I discovered the **ErrorBoundary** component in the .Net 6 framework.

[ErrorBoundaries doc from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#error-boundaries)

At first, I successfully tested this component inside a **Bazor WebAssembly** project.

Steps:

- Create a newBlazor WebAssembly project
- Create the component CustomErrorBoundary.razor (see code below)
- In MainLayout.razor surround the @Body instruction with the component CustomErrorBoundary
- In FetchData.razor throw an exception in the code (see below)

**CustomErrorBoundary**

```
    @inherits ErrorBoundary
    @if (CurrentException is null)
    {
        @ChildContent
    }
    else if (ErrorContent is not null)
    {
        @ErrorContent(CurrentException)
    }
    else
    {
        <div style="background-color: yellow; border: 2px dashed black; white-space: pre; font-family: consolas, monospace;">
            @foreach (var exception in receivedExceptions)
            {
                <div class="received-exception" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3); margin: 0.5rem; padding: 0.5rem;">
                    @exception.Message
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }

    @code {
        List<Exception> receivedExceptions = new();

        protected override Task OnErrorAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            receivedExceptions.Add(exception);
            return base.OnErrorAsync(exception);
        }

        public new void Recover()
        {
            receivedExceptions.Clear();
            base.Recover();
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

When testing this app and navigating in the FetchData, the error is thrown and displayed on the page.

[image]

So far so good. Now I would like to do the same but this time for a **.NET Maui Blazor** project.

Steps:

- Create a newBlazor .NET Maui Blazor project
- Add a the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web to the project (to benefit from ErrorBoundary)
- Restart Visual Studio (not mandatory)
- Create the component CustomErrorBoundary.razor (see code above)
- In MainLayout.razor surround the @Body instruction with the component CustomErrorBoundary
- In WeatherForecastService.cs throw an exception in the code (see below)

[image]

Unfortunately, the project crash immeadiately when trying to start it.

[image]

So to be said simpler: it seems **ErrorBoundary** is not supported in a .NET Maui Blazor project.

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    @Body
</ErrorBoundary>
```

The simple code above does not works in Blazor Maui.

So I don't know if **ErrorBoundary** is compatible with .NET Maui Blazor ? If not, how to catch any errors inside a Blazor Maui project and display it on the page ?

Comment: I hava the same issue using MudBlazor, the ErrorBoundary dosen't work

Comment: I didn't use MudBlazor so I cannot help you on that. You can still report the issue on Github (https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues).

Comment: Bronzato, did you succeed with @Shurino answer? May you please post the amended code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to decipher the error, on first look, it seems that the type ErrorBoudary that you inherit needs a dependency that is not injected in your MAUI project.

I have found a post that seems to explain your issue [Githubmemory on this issue](https://githubmemory.com/repo/bUnit-dev/bUnit/issues/410)
Basically, you need to implement the interface and then register that new class as an available service.

[Code of ErrorBoundary](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/Web/ErrorBoundary.cs,13)

[code of IErrorBoundaryLogger](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/Web/IErrorBoundaryLogger.cs,15)

I would guess the Blazor Wasm implements this by default?

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't an answer to this, and I hope this isn't bad form. I'm learning right now, I wanted to share a related code snippet in case anyone else wants to do this.

using the above example, and mudblazor. I made a custom error boundary component that displays the error in a snackbar popup.

CustomErrorBoundary.razor

```
@inherits ErrorBoundary
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar
@if (CurrentException is null)
{
    @ChildContent
}
else if (ErrorContent is not null)
{
    @ErrorContent(CurrentException)
}
else
{
    @ChildContent

        @foreach (var exception in receivedExceptions)
        {
            Snackbar.Add(@exception.Message, Severity.Error);
        }

    Recover();
}

@code {
    List<Exception> receivedExceptions = new();

    protected override Task OnErrorAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        receivedExceptions.Add(exception);
        return base.OnErrorAsync(exception);
    }

    public new void Recover()
    {
        receivedExceptions.Clear();
        base.Recover();
    }
}
```

MainLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar

<MudThemeProvider IsDarkMode="true"/>
<MudDialogProvider />
<MudSnackbarProvider />

<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar>
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())" />
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@_drawerOpen">
        <NavMenu/>
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        <CustomErrorBoundary>
            @Body
        </CustomErrorBoundary>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

@code {
    bool _drawerOpen = true;

    private void DrawerToggle()
    {
        _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am debating whether my answer only works because of MudBlazor or not, but since there is little feedback here, I will just throw it in.
I am using the default ErrorBoundary, and it is working just fine for me. Maybe something has been updated in the past 9 months?

Here is my relevant code, in MainLayout.razor:

```
<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Elevation="0">
        @* Some random MudAppBar stuff... *@
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Large" Class="my-16 pt-16">
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <ChildContent>
                    @Body
                </ChildContent>
                <ErrorContent>
                    <p class="errorUI">An error has occured. Edit this content in MainLayout.razor</p>
                </ErrorContent>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
```

I am throwing an exception in a similar way as in the question, and the error content apperas :)